# The click event does not seem to be firing when I interact with the button

Tags: google-tag-manager

I am encountering an unexpected issue while using Google Tag Manager (GTM) to capture click events on a button element.

[To provide more clarity, I have included a screenshot of the button element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ra16m.png)

[However, even when I enable the preview mode in GTM and attempt to click the button, the expected click event does not register, as shown in the GTM preview mode screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEFEb.png)

If there are any additional troubleshooting steps or insights that could help resolve this issue, I would greatly appreciate your guidance.